# Excel 2016 Function Gives #NAME Error Even Though Function Auto-Displays

Tags: excel, function, sorting, ip, vba

## Update 2

I uploaded ip_testing.xlsm to GitHub repository ([link](https://github.com/RanaDataViz/Modules_In_Excel))

---

---

## Update 1

Here is the exact formula entered in

[image]

When I evaluate error

[image]

[image]

[image]

---

---

## Original Question

I created `ExpandIP` function based on this article ([link](https://excelribbon.tips.net/T013481_Sorting_IP_Addresses.html))

When I try to use it gives `#NAME` error even though it auto-displays in drop-down

[image: ExpandIP appears on drop-down]

`#NAME` error

[image: #NAME error]

Here is the code

```
Function ExpandIP(IPAddr As String) As String
   Dim Dot1 As Integer
   Dim Dot2 As Integer
   Dim Dot3 As Integer
   Dim Octet1 As String
   Dim Octet2 As String
   Dim Octet3 As String
   Dim Octet4 As String


   Dot1 = InStr(1, IPAddr, ".", vbTextCompare)
   Dot2 = InStr(Dot1 + 1, IPAddr, ".", vbTextCompare)
   Dot3 = InStr(Dot2 + 1, IPAddr, ".", vbTextCompare)

   Octet1 = Left(IPAddr, Dot1 - 1)
   Octet2 = Mid(IPAddr, Dot1 + 1, Dot2 - Dot1 - 1)
   Octet3 = Mid(IPAddr, Dot2 + 1, Dot3 - Dot2 - 1)
   Octet4 = Mid(IPAddr, Dot3 + 1, Len(IPAddr))

   ExpandIP = Right("000" & Octet1, 3) & "."
   ExpandIP = ExpandIP & Right("000" & Octet2, 3) & "."
   ExpandIP = ExpandIP & Right("000" & Octet3, 3) & "."
   ExpandIP = ExpandIP & Right("000" & Octet4, 3)     
End Function
```

Comment: problem with arguments? Needs to be a String

Comment: Hm, I don't get that error.  Is this in a workbook module, yeah?

Comment: @BruceWayne Yes this is in workbook module

Comment: @MacroMarc I set the input field as Text. I even tried with quotes around IP address. Error persists.

Comment: Can you show the formula you're using when it gives the error? Are you positive it's spelled correctly?

Comment: @BruceWayne I entered `=ExpandIP(A1)`. See updated question.